# Чтение из файла (BufferedReader)

Tags: файлы, java

Имеется код

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt")));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Файл не найден");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Вопрос: а куда нужно положить файл [input.txt](http://input.txt), чтоб он корректно считался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

лучше корректно указать путь, например C://[input.txt](http://input.txt), а по умолчанию в каталог проекта

Comment: Когда-то давно у меня digicrime.com через netscape пыталось найти c:\autoexec.bat на линуксовом разделе. Выглядело забавно...

А говорят, что java -- платформенно-независимая.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не указывать полный путь, а только название файла - этот файл должен лежать в каталоге проекта.