# Как считать с файла в коллекцию Java

Tags: java

Мне необходимо считать текстовый файл построчно, после того как считает, необходимо получить коллекцию строк. List
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File myfile = new File(ссылка_на_файл);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(myfile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   имя_массива.add(line);
}
reader.close;
```

Comment: Хотя идея этого кода является ответом, надо привести его в приемлемый вид. В нескольких местах пропущены скобки, текстовые пояснения лучше объединить в одно слово, чтобы оно выглядело как имя переменной, а не как нечто другое.

Answer (score 4):

В сети полно примеров. Хоть бы попробовали почитать, разобраться прежде чем сюда писать. А, если после прочтения чего-то не поймете, то уже спрашивать.

Но все же скажу несколько слов касаемо вопроса: Чтение производится через потоки, можно последовательно считывать строку методом readLine() и сразу помещать в List.

[вот статья по теме](http://devcolibri.com/1141)

Кстати, здесь имеются похожие вопросы, если поискать: [первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/221398/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145925/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-bufferedreader)